podsを使用し、特定の固定ページの投稿画面にカスタムフィールドの入力画面を表示させる方法を教えていただきたいです。
podsというカスタムフィールドを使用したいと思っています。カスタムフィールドの入力画面を固定ページに表示させるまではできたのですが、固定ページの全ページに入力画面が表示され、特定の固定ページに表示させれません。
https://gyazo.com/9863c530b802374d1dc245831426ce1f
固定ページによってカスタムフィールドの入力内容を変更したいのですが、どなたか知っている方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？
googleで『pods 固定ページ』など検索したのですが、情報が少なく、プラグインのリファレンスや解説を翻訳しても見つけることができませんでした。どこかに固定ページのIDなどを指定する箇所があると思うのですが、見つけれませんでした。。お忙しいところすみません、よろしくお願いいたします。
ACFの騒動があった為こちらのプラグインに乗り換えたいとおもっています。
